# Divi Header issue after updating Divi Theme

Tags: wordpress

[image]

This morning, I updated my divi Theme, and noticed that when I scroll, all of my content goes ON TOP of my header now (see Screenshot). Another issue that has appeared is all pages which contain icons/images with animation, do not scroll at all! Has anybody experienced this before? I would be so thankful for any tips on how to fix this!

Best regards

Comment: Please contact the support of DIVI Theme for this problem. Also we cannot help without any code, or at least the link of your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I got in touch with Divi support. If this happens to anyone else, here is the solution!

Dive-> Theme Options -> Additional CSS:

```
#main-header {
   z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your previous CSS is deleted while updating the Divi Theme. Please reinsert the previous CSS and It will show the right result for your header.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can roll back the previous changes from **Divi -> Theme Options -> Updates Tab -> Roll back.**